# What is Minecraft's database?

Tags: databases, minecraft-modding

I was wondering, what kind of database does Minecraft use? Is it a relational database, maybe something common like MySQL? Do we even know what he's using?

And maybe even a better question, SHOULD he be doing it that way? What type of database should be used?

Comment: The format currently used for level data is described at http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Beta_Level_Format.

Comment: I love the "should" question. As if Notch is wrong. Hah. :-P

Comment: Do you mean the database on the client, or the database on the server that's managing authentication, etc.

Comment: Managing authentication is not a database. It's a plain text file with account names, called Whitelist ;)

Comment: @Marco i think he means when you log in to the authentication server when you first start up the game, not server whitelists

Comment: @Mike Lentini: Ah, right. Got the wrong idea. ;)

Comment: @Ricket What are you suggesting? Notch is a god amongst men! ;)

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck That's what I was suggesting, jokingly. The "should he be doing it that way" questions whether he is correct/optimal. :)

Comment: @Tim: come on, that is a totally uncalled random nitpick. It is plainly **obvious** he refers to the database on the client.

Comment: I'd hardly say it's obvious - after all, the question mentions MySQL but the game clearly does not ship with MySQL (and when you play it in the browser, how could it?)

Comment: This is a bad question, and I would honestly downvote it if I could

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Minecraft saves the world data and the player data. Saving the world data is done in multiplayer and singleplayer with the same method. It saves everything in a single `.mcr` file.
Previous versions of minecraft saved the data in a file structure with many files, which was slower, I think.
I don´t know this exactly, but I guess that a database for world saving would be not the best, because the data is saved in intervals of 15 minutes or so and a database is not designed for saving all data at the same time.

The player data on multiplayer servers is saved in a `.dat` file. I don´t think that this player data is saved in a SQLite database or something similar, because using a database for requesting once and saving every 5 minutes or so is also not the best.

**To sum it up:**
I think Notch doesn´t even use any database, because it does not make sense since every data is kept in memory and only saved in intervals of minutes.

Comment: Notch uses a straight up binary format that's been compressed. His reason? Performance and space probably.

Comment: I am pretty sure the `.dat` is used in singleplayer too, for player positions and data.

Comment: @The Communist Duck: I looked into my savegames and could only find a 
`.mcr`. A `.dat` would make more sense, but maybe it is bundled with the `.mcr`.

Comment: There is a level.dat for every level; I use it with the level tools site (URL forgotten) to find seeds and do the random-teleport thing.